# Dropdown child menu not displaying any data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have this simple dropdown menu in my codeigniter form. When clicking dzongkhag(district) it should display the list of geogs(towns), but, instead it do not do so. The drop down menu that I have is not the best one but that is what I could come up with after trying (for many weeks) many times unsuccessfully. I will be grateful if someone could help me out/solve/advice on this.

Here are the snippets.
view.php

```
<label >Dzongkhag: </label>
<select id="user_dzongkhag" name="dzongkhag" >
  <option>Select Dzongkhag</option>
  <option value="Bumthang">Bumtang</option>
  <option value="Chhukha">Chhukha</option>
  <option value="Dagana">Dagana</option>
  <option value="Gasa">Gasa</option>
  <option value="Haa">Haa</option>
  <option value="Lhuentse">Lhuntse</option>
  <option value="Monggar">Monggar</option>
  <option value="Paro">Paro</option>
  <option value="Pema Gatshel">Pema Gatshel</option>
  <option value="Punakha">Punakha</option>
  <option value="Samdrup Jongkhar">Samdrup Jongkhar</option>
  <option value="Samtse">Samtse</option>
  <option value="Sarpang">Sarpang</option>
  <option value="Thimphu">Thimphu</option>
  <option value="Trashigang">Trashigang</option>
  <option value="Trashi Yangtse">Trashi Yangtse</option>
  <option value="Trongsa">Trongsa</option>
  <option value="Tsirang">Tsirang</option>
  <option value="Wangdue Phodrang">Wangdue Phodrang</option>
  <option value="Zhemgang">Zhemgang</option>                
</select>

<label >Geog:</label>
<select id="user_geog" name="geog" >
  <option> select geog</option>
</select>
```

javascript (which I implement it in the view.php instead of js folder)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#user_dzongkhag').change(function(){
    $('#user_geog').html('<option> Fetching...</option>');

    var user_dzongkhag =$('#user_dzongkhag').val();

    //alert(new_div);

    $.ajax({
      type:"post",

      data:"user_dzongkhag="+user_dzongkhag,
      url:"<?php echo site_url('ajax/select_auth_geog/'); ?>",
      cache:false,
      success:function(resp){
        //alert(resp);
        $('#user_geog').html(resp);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

controller.php

```
public function select_auth_geog(){
  $user_dzongkhag= $this->input->post('user_dzongkhag');
  $returnGeog=$this->ajax_model->select_auth_geog($user_dzongkhag);
  foreach ($returnGeog as $key) {
    echo '<option value="'.$key['name'].'">'.$key['name'].' </option>';
  }
}
```

model.php

```
public function select_auth_geog($user_dzongkhag){
  if($user_dzongkhag=='Bumtang'){
    $user_dzongkhag=1;
  }elseif($user_dzongkhag=='Chhukha'){
    $user_dzongkhag=2;
  }elseif($user_dzongkhag=='Dagana'){
    $user_dzongkhag=3;
  }elseif($user_dzongkhag=='Gasa'){
    $user_dzongkhag=4;
  }elseif($user_dzongkhag=='Haa'){
    $user_dzongkhag=5;
  }elseif($user_dzongkhag=='Lhuntse'){
    $user_dzongkhag=6;
  }elseif($user_dzongkhag=='Monggar'){
  ......
  ........
```

Comment: No problem. :) I find clean code easier to read.  What happens when you un-comment the `alert(resp);` in your JS?  Also, if you echo an `<option>` at the start of your `select_auth_geog` function in your controller, does it work?

Comment: alert(resp) gives an alert message box. and echoing an option did not produce anything. Not so sure, if I have done the echo part correctly @Jonathan

Comment: Is the alert message box empty?  For the echo, put this as the first line in your controller's `select_auth_geog` function: `echo '<option value="candy">Candy</option>';`  Essentially, I want to know if it's getting as far as the controller.

Comment: @Jonathan, yes the message box is empty. The output from the echo is `<option value="candy">Candy</option><div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">



<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>



<p>Severity: Notice</p>

<p>Message:  Undefined index: name</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/ajax.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 152</p>
</div><div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined index: name</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/ajax.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 152</p>
`

Comment: Alright, you can remove that echo since we now know it's getting as far as the controller.  Instead, just before the foreach in your controller, put this line: `var_dump($returnGeog);`.  You could replace the `alert` with a `console.log(resp)` if you want, and look in your console for the returned data.  Or simply open the network tools.  You can get those by hitting F12 in Chrome or Ctrl+Shift+i in Firefox if my memory serves me correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching these two lines, you may be deleting the select box value before it is stored in user_dzongkhag.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#user_dzongkhag').change(function(){
    $('#user_geog').html('<option> Fetching...</option>');  <-------------

    var user_dzongkhag =$('#user_dzongkhag').val();         <-------------

    //alert(new_div);

    $.ajax({
      type:"post",

      data:"user_dzongkhag="+user_dzongkhag,
      url:"<?php echo site_url('ajax/select_auth_geog/'); ?>",
      cache:false,
      success:function(resp){
        //alert(resp);
        $('#user_geog').html(resp);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: tried your suggestion @oMiKeY, the dropdown list simply displays the word Fectching